# Copying a multiline text into a single cell in Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I want to copy the following:

```
line1


line 2


line 3
```

into a single cell in Excel.

I know that I can use the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac to create a line break in the cell, but here I want to copy paste in a single cell, not typing its content.

Here is what I get:

[image]

I want it in a single cell with line breaks:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To paste multi-line content in Excel, all you need to do is double click the new cell (so you see the arrow 'thing' blinking), and paste (ctrl + V):

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this does NOT work in Excel 2013.  You have to paste into the editor strip above the cell display area.

Comment: This works with Office 2016.

Answer (score 17):

If you have to do this for more than one cell:

> 1. Replace all linebreaks in word (`^p` or `^l`) with something you can
>    replace (I use `LINEBRK`).
> 2. Paste into Excel.
> 3. Replace all `LINEBRK` with the newline/linefeed character generated by
>    `Alt+0010` (hold down `Alt` on your keyboard and then hit `0010` on your number pad) or hit `Ctrl + J`.
> 4. Re-do/re-apply **Wrap Text** in Excel.

Source: [Remove Replace or Separate by Line Breaks](https://excelunplugged.com/2016/05/24/remove-replace-or-separate-by-line-breaks-alt-enter-including-vba/)

Comment: Note for other n00Bs like me: to enter that into the REPLACE box, hold down <ALT> key and type 0010 using the numeric keypad.

Comment: I couldn't get alt+0010 to work, so I ended up using a formula in a new column.  I also had to enable word wrap on the column.  `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "LINEBRK", CHAR(10))`

Comment: Upvote because it works in bulk (the chosen answer only works for a single cell). This works even if you want to insert a lot of text into Excel, even though it is a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Comment: What about for a Mac?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem now.
I found a different (in some cases a better) solution.
If you can, surround the clipboard content with quotation marks:

```
"line1


line 2


line 3"
```

Comment: Interestingly it does not work if you copy it from the browser like this (I assume due to formatting information copied along with the text data). So if you want to try this, copy it to a text editor first, then copy it from there and drop it to Excel. That works.

Comment: Awesome tip. This can even be used to paste multiple cells each containing multiline text, for example: 

"row 1 line 1\n
\n
row 1 line 2"\n
"row 2 line 1\n
\n
row 2 line 2" (\n stands for new line)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an "interesting" "funny" thing about pasting like this in Excel...

The choices currently "set" in the Data|Text to Columns functionality in the Ribbon change how Paste puts this data into a cell.

Select some data, even a single cell, and click in the Ribbon to start that function. The dialogue box appears and choose `Delimited`, then `Next`. Now you have the list of possible delimiters Excel expects adn the ability to specify a nice "Other" if you'd like. If the only one checked is `Tab`, you will be able to paste the kind of data you mention into a single cell with those individual bits on different lines in that cell, just as you wish here. If, for instance, `Space` is checked, you will see the data you wanted on separate lines in a single cell broken into wholely separate cells like you show. It goes more mutli-cells, right to left, for spaces, but I've seen it go multi-line as well with internet data.

Why? Um, who knows? Surprisingly, not many even seem to have seen this either. But basically, clear ALL those checkboxes, not hard to check them again if you really DO want to do `Text to Columns`, so, you know... just clear them. Then try the pasting and I'll give odds it goes just fine.

All those other approaches work too, they just require some to a LOT of extra work and other programs and so on. Use the easiest if the above does not help this time.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for Office >2019

[Accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/759473/1322351) doesn't work in Office 2019.

The quick and dirty way after some experimenting is to copy the cells, **paste them into any text editor to get rid of the formatting**, copy the text from there, double click in the cell and paste.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long one. I will preface this with the fact that I always wrap cell contents with double quotes when any newline character exists in my cells.

The issue I have primarily ran into is when I have internal quotes inside a cell that I am trying to paste in.

**Example (paste into text editor then copy from there):**

```
"line 1
line "2"
line 3"
```

**Excel interprets this as:**

**Cell 1:**

```
line 1
line 2"
```

**Cell 2 (on next row):**

```
line 3"
```

The solution to this is to escape the quote character. In Excel, you can escape the inner quote characters with another quote character (""). The cell still needs to be wrapped in singular quotes.

**Now we have (paste into text editor then copy from there):**

```
"line 1
line ""2""
line 3"
```

**Which Excel interprets correctly as:**

**Cell 1:**

```
line 1
line "2"
line 3
```