# How to copy multiple lines from MS word and paste them into Multiple lines in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a MS word file containing names and emails each name and email is in a separate line, I want to copy it into excel, is there any way that I can copy the whole page and have it pasted into separate lines?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Just copy from Word and paste into Excel, and they will indeed end up on separate lines. But I guess you actually want them to be in separate **cells**, too. Well, in that case first change the spaces to Tab characters in Word (Ctrl-H, replace...), and then do the copy-and-paste part.

Answer (score 0):

I'd mark this as a duplicate, but I don't see how. I'd add a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Anyway, follow the instructions from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1029030/433678) to do what you're asking to do.

1. **Find and replace** all line breaks in Word (represented by `^p` or `^l` in Word's **Find what** field) with some text that you can do a find and replace operation on later (For example, find and replace all the paragraph and/or line breaks with the text `LINEBRK`).
2. **Copy** what you want and **paste** into Excel.
3. **Replace** all instances of `LINEBRK` with the [newline/linefeed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) that is [generated](https://excelunplugged.com/2016/05/24/remove-replace-or-separate-by-line-breaks-alt-enter-including-vba/) by hitting `Ctrl + J` on your keyboard or by hitting `Alt+0010` (hold down `Alt` on your keyboard and type `0010` on your number pad).
4. Re-do/re-apply **Wrap Text** in Excel if needed.