# Is there any way to keep MySQL code in one cell, while also keeping the MySQL syntax colouring?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Whenever I paste SQL code it automatically colours it. Like this:

[image: Example of SQL coding]

Which is great. However, I don't like how it separates the lines of code into different rows. But when I try and paste the code into one cell, it loses its colouring:

[image: Example]

Is there any way to keep the code in one cell, while also keeping the colouring?

Comment: Copy/paste formatting? The little icon that looks like a paintbrush ...

Comment: As Mawg said, paste with source formatting right than paste with target formatting.

Comment: Where is the paintbrush icon

Comment: Excel is quite limited in terms of different formatting within cells. You might succeed using this workaround: https://superuser.com/a/1029030/427317